# Shortcut to maximize the last application that was in focus

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-yosemite

I wanted to know how i can switch between applications that are running using the keyboard shortcut.Say I have 4 applications running xcode , terminal , chrome and foo. Now suppose I am on chrome and would like to switch to Xcode. I do this  by doing Alt-Tab shortcut. Now I would like to get back to chrome and I am on xcode. I usually accomplish this by Alt-Tab and then moving back and forth between the selection box. My question is if there is a faster way to toggle and move to the last active application using a shortcut key.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on this because all I can find are references to command-tab and the behavior seems to match what you're asking already (automatically switching back to the last focused application, so why is there a selection box). Maybe you have a custom switcher / maybe there's an answer here? http://superuser.com/questions/193922/is-there-any-program-or-way-to-make-mac-os-xs-%E2%8C%98-tab-behave-like-windows-alt-ta

Comment: I believe command+tab moves forward to the next most recently used application in a list of open applications.What if my last application was not the most used application ? http://www.techlicious.com/tip/the-most-useful-mac-keyboard-shortcuts/